# How to press the enter-key inside an input field with pure JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want to simulate an enter-press inside a text-input-field that i can identify using an id. First i will find my textfield by `document.getElementById`. This works pretty fine. Next, i want to click inside the textfield so set the cursor inside it.
And last i want to press enter. I have no idea how i can do this. And I couldn't find any solution here.

My code looks a follow:

```
let plzField = document.getElementById("filter"); //find the text-field (works)
plzField.click(); // works
plzField.enter(); // does not work
```

Please help!

Comment: what is the result of pressing the actual enter key?

Comment: Yeah, if pressing an enter key calls a function then just call that `function()`. If it submits a form then you can call the `.submit()` method on the form. Or you can find the submit button and `.click()` it. I don't know what else it might be.

Comment: That particular behavior triggers a submit event (if that input is a child of a form). `.submit()` method yields the same result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+simulate+enter+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You might want tot have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Keyup Event Listener. keycode for enter is 13.

For More Example, Please visit https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_trigger_button_enter

```js
let plzField = document.getElementById("filter");

plzField.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="filter" />
```

Answer (score 3):

As per your question, it seems, that you want to detect on enter event occurred or not. In pure Javascript, there is no such onenter event, but with `eventCode` or `eventName` you can check that.

You need to apply filter as you applied in you code and then you need to check for `keyPress()` event and within this event you need to check `event.code || event.key'
like below

```js
var textInput = document.getElementById('foo');
function enter() {
    var keyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        code: 'Enter',
        key: 'Enter',
        charKode: 13,
        keyCode: 13,
        view: window
    });

    textInput.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
}

textInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
enter()
```

```html
<input type="text" id="foo" />
```

Comment: this is not the thing i need. you made a trigger how is launching when the enter key will be pressed. i want to simulate a key-press

Comment: this is a trigger and not a simulater!

Comment: If you want to simulate it, then first you need to create it, because in js there is nothing like `onenter` event. Updating my code for that now

Comment: Check now updated snippet @LukasGlaser

Comment: I think this was working for you @LukasGlaser

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    $("#id_of_button").click();
  }
});

$("#pw").keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    $("#myButton").click();
  }
});

$("#myButton").click(function() {
  alert("Button code executed.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Username:<input id="username" type="text"><br> Password:&nbsp;
<input id="pw" type="password"><br>
<button id="myButton">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You are not triggering anything here. I made you a snippet.

Comment: sorry you did not understand me. i do not want to trigger i want to simulate!